# How to make archlinux lamp dev friendly?

Tags: php, lamp, archlinux

I switched from Ubuntu to Manjaro on my little php dev netbook.

I follow the Archlinux wiki to install a LAMP stack.
I put all my websites projects in the **public_html**.

It works well if I manually create all the files.
But not when I extract some files (old projects that I zipped).

So on Ubuntu, I changed APACHE_RUN_USER and APACHE_RUN_GROUP, but I can't find them on Manjaro (Archlinux).

What should I do to develop like I did on Archlinux based distro ?

Comment: I'd say instead of changing the normal system setup you should fix ownership and permissions of those files you extract. That should do the trick. Unless there is some other issue which you did not mention.

Comment: Also, `public_html` sounds very much like being located in some users home directory (I do not know Manjaro or Archlinux, but that is the typical location of _personal_ web documents on a linux based system. For development I'd always prefer to use a neutral (non user specific) location of web projects.

Comment: So you recommend me to use (on Ubuntu) /var/www instead of public_html even for dev? And fix permission manually to enable writing for current user?

Comment: That or some "development specific location" like /var/develop or whatever, from within you map single folders into your web root by means of an `Alias` directive inside the http servers configuration. Or by symlinking. Endless possibilities, that is more a question of personal preferences.

Comment: Sorry, one thing I forgot: that suggestion only applies of that is a _personal_ linux system. If that system is used by multiple users / developers then obviously other aspects have to be taken into account.

Comment: I'm not a linux server expert, I usually use a already created vagrant box for development. But my netbook has a really limited CPU. So you suggest me to put my website in `/var/www` for example and create a symlink with `ln` command to a user location, for example `/home/$USER/web_projects`?

Comment: I meant to map the development projects locations into the "normal" web space served by your http server. You can do that either via the http servers configuration or by using a symlink. Keeping the development stuff in a users personal home folder has two side aspects: 1. an annoying url to access it, having the typical `~user` inside the path and 2. permission problems in case of other processes requiring access to the ressources (for example cron or backup jobs). This is why _I prefer_ a neutral location of my projects. But as said: those are personal preferences in the end.